Jackson read byte image
everyone, I would like to serialize byte images and pass them to Jackson, my server, to serialize them correctly at the client level I have this error
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING; how can I solve this problem?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
